# Resume/Restart app when email arrives

Tags: c#, .net, email, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I want an app to be "revived" even if it has been suspended/terminated, when an email arrives. This has to be done without any dedicated web service, only using email's Idle ("Push") command, or something else included in a standard email server. (I do know how to use `Idle`. What I don't know is how to get a suspended/terminated app to be revived by it.)

If this can't be done, and there's a way to poll the email server, that would be a workaround. But as far as I know - that's totally impossible with Windows Store apps because they get suspended/terminated when they're in the background.

Comment: If you post what you've tried, others might be more inclined to help because they'd have a better starting point.

Comment: There's not much to try here. Anyone who has experience with UWP will understand the question. UWP has many built in limitations which probably make this impossible. But I'm asking because maybe I'm wrong. But thanks. I did realize thanks to your comment, that my question needs editing. Done now.

Comment: A good option may be to use a push notification to the device. That way, you can add a payload to the message that you can use when the app launches with user interaction.

Comment: @JamesCroft92 Thanks. But a) That would mean a dedicated web service as opposed to just the email server, and b) This would not wake the app. Both in contrast with the requirements.

Comment: There are background triggers: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.background.systemtriggertype.aspx. But not for email, so I don't think this is possible without a dedicated server for push notification...

Answer (score 1):

As a first attempt I would use a Background Task triggered by a [TimeTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.background.timetrigger.aspx) and pull there. The one downside is that that the minimum trigger interval for a Background task is 15 minutes, but with this imho you can have a working version very quickly. (With some drawbacks...)

There is also a SocketActivityTrigger. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt617016)
If you dig deeper into the protocol of your mail server maybe you can implement something better with that.

And then from your Background Task you can launch the app (or show a Toast notification, which launches the App...)

There is also a concept in UWP called extended execution, which can be useful. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt590969.aspx) (although I would not use it for this use case...).